# Inspect Google Calendar for Appointments

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api, google-workspace

Is it possible to inspect a Google Calendar for created appointments using Apps Script? I am able to get event details over a date range, but would also like to pull out potential appointment slots that have been created in a Workspace account.

If this is possible, how?

Thanks

Comment: check freebusy in the documentation

Comment: [Calendar.getEvents()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar#getEvents(Date,Date))

Comment: @Cooper getEvents only gets events and not appointments

Comment: @DalmTo searched freebusy but no results, any pointers please?

Comment: I always make appointments with events

Comment: My calendar has no appointment objects in the documentation

Comment: @Cooper any links you could share please?

Comment: I have no links to non existent objects.  [Google Apps Script Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference)

Comment: [non existent objects](https://www.nonexistentobjects.com)